# Userpicture method automatically rotates picture

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fill a shape with various pictures (depending on variable), which works fine for some pictures. However, for some pictures it automatically rotates the picture by 90°. I really have no clue why that happens. Can you guys help? The code is as follows:

```
    Sub insertpic()

    Dim Name As String
    Dim Name2 As String

    Name = Worksheets("namesource").Range("B2").Value
    Name2 = Name & ".JPG"


    Sheets("destination").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 3")).Select

        With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .UserPicture "C:\Users\Path & Name2 & ""
            .TextureTile = msoFalse
        End With
   End sub
```

Mostly learn VBA by recording macros so bear with me please.

Thanks a lot

Best,
S

The 2 pictures. Picture A is inserted in the right orientation; Picture B is rotated by 90° when inserted:

[Picture A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXmuv.jpg)
[Picture B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xu3W.jpg)

Comment: I guess *"C:\Users\Path\" **&** Name2 & ""*

Comment: Consider renaming variables `Name` and `Name2` to `Filename` and `FilenameWithExtension` (assuming you can't just use one  of them)  -- as `Name` is already an object in Excel. Also, are the images a mixture of landscape/portrait to begin with (outside of Excel, you might need to open/check their orientation with some image viewer/application)?

Comment: Find one of the images (that you know gets automatically rotated), then check that particular image in an image viewer -- just to check if its orientation is 'rotated' to begin with.

Comment: @JohnyL: What do you mean by your comment? Path is basically the path to my file, which I did not want to insert in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @chillin: The pictures are all in portrait orientation. Also changed the names of the variables, does not work unfortunately. Maybe I will just upload 2 pictures, one of them being inserted in the right and the other one in the wrong orientation?

Comment: I've had a look at the documentation for `ShapeRange.Fill` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shaperange.fill), but I can't find any parameter/functionality that dictates or relates to the orientation/rotation of the image. Are you able to fix the rotation in Excel via the graphical user interface? If it's possible through the GUI, try recording a macro whilst making the necessary changes, then check what properties/members are involved.

Comment: Also, I think it will be difficult to 'recognise' an image that needs rotating (purely via code), unless you can get away with some simple logic like `if image's width is greater than it's height, then rotate 90 degrees` (this assumes and might only work if all of your images are portrait/vertical, which isn't robust).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is becaus of ExIf tag of photo that excel vba don't check it an shows the photo directly!
You can open the photo which have rotation problem: open with Windows Paint program.
Now just save it overwriting on itself. Close the Paint.
Your problem is solved ;)